# Ring datatype in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, matrix, circular-list

I wanted to write something that would be useful for the indices of a grid where if one walked off the edge of the grid they would re enter on the opposite side. This could in theory help with checking for special cases when checking for neighbours to a certain position on the grid. For example the neighbours of position (0, 0) on a 10 x 10 grid would be (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (9, 9), (0, 9), (1, 9), (9, 0), (9, 1).

```
def _adj_index(method):
    def _dec(instance, *args):
        if isinstance(args[0], int):
            index = args[0] % len(instance)
            return method(instance, index, *args[1:])
        return method(instance, args)
    return _dec


class Ring(list):
    """
    Ring datatype.
    """

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            for i in xrange(len(self)):
                yield self[i]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            slice = item[0]
            return Ring([
                self[i]
                for i in xrange(slice.start, slice.stop, slice.step)])
        return super(Ring, self).__getitem__(item)

    __getitem__ = _adj_index(__getitem__)
    __setitem__ = _adj_index(list.__setitem__)
    __delitem__ = _adj_index(list.__delitem__)

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return Ring([
            self[x]
            for x in range(i, j)])
```

I don't like the special case for `__getitem__` of having to check if it is an integer or a tuple containing a `slice`.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Great first post +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit from builtin data types - there's a `UserList` type that's more appropriate.

On top of that, you probably shouldn't inherit from `UserList` either: your code is not a `list` and doesn't fill its contractual obligations. This is a time to favour composition over inheritance.

Before I look at implementing this, here are a few quick things I noticed. One is

```
if isinstance(item, tuple):
    ...
```

in `__getitem__`, which doesn't seem to work since `_adj_index` is packing any tuples it gets into *another* tuple.

Another thing was the use of `for i in xrange(len(self)):`, which would be much simpler if you could just do `for i in self._items` - another advantage of composition. You can actually manage this with `super(Ring, self).__iter__()`, though.

Your `__getslice__` returns another ring; this seems strange - a slice of a ring is rarely itself also a ring. If you have a ring of paper and cut a section out, that section has ends!

Finally, your `__str__` and `__repr__` are the default ones for `list`, which is entirely misleading and very bad practice.

Back to the point, looking at [the abstract base classes in `collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (later moved to [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)), the only interfaces it makes sense to support are `Container` and `Iterable`, since the class doesn't have a `__len__`. Adding `__{get,set,del}item__` and `__repr__` on top of that would give something like

```
def _adj_index(method):
    def _dec(instance, *args):
        if isinstance(args[0], int):
            index = args[0] % len(instance._items)
            return method(instance._items, index, *args[1:])
        return method(instance._items, args)
    return _dec

class Ring:
    """
    Ring datatype.
    """

    def __init__(self, items):
        self._items = list(items)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            for i in xrange(len(self._items)):
                yield self._items[i]

    __getitem__ = _adj_index(list.__getitem__)
    __setitem__ = _adj_index(list.__setitem__)
    __delitem__ = _adj_index(list.__delitem__)

    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        return [self[x] for x in range(i, j)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ring({})".format(self._items)
```

This discards `__getitem__` since it's no longer needed but keeps it similar to your code.

`__iter__` could just delegate to `itertools.cycle`.

`__getslice__` [is deprecated and has been for ages](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__). Let's consider doing this properly:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if isinstance(idx, slice):
        return ???

    return self._items[idx % len(self._items)]
```

What should `???` be? Well, we'd like something akin to

```
[self[i] for i in xrange(idx.start, idx.stop, idx.step)]
```

but `start`, `stop` or `step` might be `None`. We can say that `start` and `stop` should not be `None` (since both directions extend infinitely), but `step` can reasonably be asked to default to 1. Unfortunately, `slice.indices` isn't appropriate here, as with other tricks you can normally use.

Thus:

```
step = 1 if idx.step is None else idx.step
return [self[i] for i in xrange(idx.start, idx.stop, step)]
```

Now, `__setitem__` probably has no good semantics for slice assignment because:

- If a slice is larger than `len(self._items)`, there is no obvious cannonical mapping on how to handle the assignment.
- If a slice crosses through the start index (has `idx % len(self._items) == 0`) and assigns to a slice of a different size, there is no obvious way to decide where the new start is moved to.

You could restrict slice assignments to slices of the same size, and on slices no more than `len(self._items)` in size - but then you're not giving much bang for the buck. For this reason, I think `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` should remain as they are, operating only on integers.

However, `_adj_index` is not worth its cost. You could just implement them as

```
def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
    if not isinstance(idx, int):
        raise TypeError("Ring indices must be integers, not {}".format(type(idx)))

    self._items[idx % len(self._items)] = value

def __delitem__(self, idx):
    if not isinstance(idx, int):
        raise TypeError("Ring indices must be integers, not {}".format(type(idx)))

    del self._items[idx % len(self._items)]
```

(the error mirrors that of indexing lists).

In the scheme of things, this code is simpler, faster and contains not too much logical duplication. However, deduplication is nice, so one could merely add a `_from_integer_index` method:

```
def _from_integer_index(self, idx):
    if not isinstance(idx, int):
        raise TypeError("Ring indices must be integers, not {}".format(type(idx)))

    return idx % len(self._items)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if isinstance(idx, slice):
        step = 1 if idx.step is None else idx.step
        return [self[i] for i in xrange(idx.start, idx.stop, step)]

    return self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)]

def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
    self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)] = value

def __delitem__(self, idx):
    del self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)]
```

In this case, wrapper methods do not seem to be the most appropriate solution to the problem.

This also allows checking for indexing 0-length rings.

All together:

```
import itertools

class Ring:
    """
    Ring datatype.
    """

    def __init__(self, items):
        self._items = list(items)

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.cycle(self._items)

    def _from_integer_index(self, idx):
        if not isinstance(idx, int):
            raise TypeError("Ring indices must be integers, not {}".format(type(idx)))

        if not len(self._items):
            raise IndexError("Indexing empty ring")

        return idx % len(self._items)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, slice):
            step = 1 if idx.step is None else idx.step
            return [self[i] for i in xrange(idx.start, idx.stop, step)]

        return self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        del self._items[self._from_integer_index(idx)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Ring({})".format(self._items)
```